# How to use double quotation marks (") in usage messages?

Tags: usage-messages

I have the following code:

```
Remove[f];
f::usage = "f[\"message\"] prints the message";
f[message_] := Print[message];
```

The usage message works except **the quotation marks which are not shown in the information popup**.

[image: Mathematica Wrong Usage Message]

As an alternative one could use `\\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]` and `\\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]` but it is a bit long to write:

```
Remove[f];
f::usage = "f[\\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]message\\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]] prints the message";
f[message_] := Print[message];
```

With the resulting popup:

[image: Mathematica Curly Quotes Usage Message]

**Do you know any way to make this shorter or get Mathematica to show the normal quotation marks?**

Comment: Your first example appears to work fine in my Mathematica 12.1 on MacOS 10.15.3.

Comment: @CarlLange Good to know. I’ll try it in a few days. I’m still on Mathematica 11.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way around that, making use of the very-hard-to-work-with string-embedded syntax for boxes:

```
Remove[f]
f[a_] := 1;
f::usage = "\!\(f[\*StyleBox[\\\"message\\\", \"TI\", ShowStringCharacters->True]]\) generates a plot of \!\(\*StyleBox[\"f\", \"TI\"]\) as a function of \!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]\) from \!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"min\", \"TI\"]]\) to \!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"max\", \"TI\"]]\).";
```

What did I do here? First I took the `::usage` message for `Plot`, coped out the first line, and then made modifications of the argument structure by hand. This will look like:

[image]

The styling trick is that I took the first `StyleBox` in the message for `Plot` and added a `ShowStringCharacters->True`

One weird thing that seems to come from how Mathematica parses these templates, if you want to add spaces to the message you need to do them in a `RowBox` and change the formatting a bit, e.g.:

```
Remove[f]
f[a_] := 1;
f::usage = "\!\(f[\*StyleBox[RowBox[{\"\\\"this\", \" \", \"is\", \" \", \"a\", \" \", \"message\\\"\"}], \"TI\", ShowStringCharacters->True]]\) generates a plot of \!\(\*StyleBox[\"f\", \"TI\"]\) as a function of \!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"]\) from \!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"min\", \"TI\"]]\) to \!\(\*SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"x\", \"TI\"], StyleBox[\"max\", \"TI\"]]\).";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a tutorial how to use these boxes in general? Please, can you explain what the usage string exactly means?

Comment: The best tutorial is to look around at stuff on the site. In general most things that the FE renders, like `Style` are represented as a "box", e.g. `StyleBox`. The format `\!\(\*<body>\)` means that whatever is inside `<body>` will be rendered as boxes, not as a string. That's about it.

Comment: Ok thank you. The only thing which I could not find was "TI" in StringBox. How is it used/useful?

Comment: Ah the `"TI"` is an italic text style that the FE uses all over the place, but that I wouldn't worry about. The only reason I left it in was to show that I copied this stuff directly from the usage message for `Plot`. You can get rid of it everywhere it occurs without worry.

Comment: Thank you again. Note for others: **You can reverse engineer the usage messages by printing e.g. File::usage and copy and paste it into a string literal ("")**

Comment: One problem I found is that if the "message" contains spaces it breaks. E.g. if one wants to make the usage message f["This is a message"]

Comment: @Qbyte see the update